# Windows 10: Ctrl-Win-Right shortcut not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just installed Windows 10.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> doesn't work to change virtual desktops.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> works fine, as does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>NumpadRight</kbd>.

Oh, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> works to turn the screen on its side.

I don't know how to debug this at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: Saw [your comment](http://superuser.com/questions/963270/windows-10-ctrl-win-right-shortcut-not-working#comment1319360_963285) that your laptop keyboard was causing the trouble. That really stinks. Would you mind ratting out which PC manufacturer (and model) it was?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### This is key jamming. You'll need to upgrade to a higher-quality keyboard.

- Most keyboards use [matrix circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_matrix_circuit) for keypress detection and cannot detect simultaneous presses of certain combinations of three keys. The specific combinations that cannot be detected depend on the keyboard model. In these situations, the keyboard will not register the keypress. On your keyboard, the matrix as laid out inside your keyboard is unable to handle the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> combination.
- More expensive keyboards generally have better isolation among keys and do not suffer from such jamming. Generally, any keyboard with some degree of "anti-ghosting" should not suffer from this issue. The best keyboards have "n-key rollover" and can handle any number of simultaneous keypresses; these keyboards are generally very expensive and should not be necessary to address this issue. **See: [Wikipedia article on keyboard rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29).**

Comment: I guess you're right.  It's my laptop keyboard, which is a bit of a pain.  I tried another keyboard and it works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Since windows doesn't allow changing keyword shortcuts,
The only option that remains is to map another key on your keyword to WIN key.

I used [sharpkeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) and re-mapped my RAlt key to WIN key.
Now i can use Ctrl+RAlt+Arrow to move around.

Another option is to use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

```
LCtrl & Left::sendevent {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Left down}{Lwin up}{LCtrl up}{Left up}
LCtrl & Right::sendevent {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Right down}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}{Right up}
```

Create a file with `.ahk` extention and use the above code.
You will be able to move around with `LCtrl + Arrow` keys.

I recommend using `sharpkeys` ( it's much simpler and easier to work with ).

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue with the Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> combo not switching Virtual Desktops. A workaround that worked for me is using the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on my laptop's keyboard. Right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

It is more likely that the shortcut it not working becauseat the current time when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> you are not moving to the next virtual desktop because you dont have one active.

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> this will create a virtual desktop then you can swap with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>

You can also push <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to show your desktop in a view that has an option on the bottom to add a new one manually and you can also close them from this page.

Comment: Format key presses as `<KBD>Tab</KBD>` just FYI.... Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a keyboard that has a options to lock "windows key". Make sure you are not locking the windows key. specially in gaming keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue.  I just installed Win10 on a computer.  The key combination was not working.  Then I tried using CTRL-TAB and it worked.  At the top of the screen was a small view of the desktop followed by a large plus sign.  I pressed the plus sign and another desktop was created.  Then the CTRL-Win-(Left/Right) started working.  I guess I had to create another desktop first in order to be able to use the switching.